# Fully qualified class names for specific package?

Tags: java, intellij-idea

Is it possible to force fully qualified class names for **specific package**?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can't do that with the Java compiler. But there are several static source analysis tools out there that you could use.

You can force fully qualified class names for certain packages by disallowing `import` statements for those packages - in that case, the code using classes in these packages can only do so with fully qualified names.

For example, you can use the [`IllegalImport` module in Checkstyle](http://checkstyle.sourceforge.net/config_imports.html#IllegalImport):

One of the examples on the page I linked above shows how you can disallow imports for certain packages:

> To configure the check so that it rejects packages java.io.* and
>   java.sql.*:
>
> ```
> <module name="IllegalImport">
>   <property name="illegalPkgs" value="java.io, java.sql"/>
> </module>
> ```

*Quoted from [Checkstyle documentation](http://checkstyle.sourceforge.net/config_imports.html#IllegalImport)*

Comment: The best option so far without using anything else, would be to disable the import for those packages, as you said. Considering that IntelliJ has an option to always use fully qualified names, iIt's weird that it does not have an option to filter witch packages you want to always use fully qualified names. Thanks for the tip about Checkstyle, I'll definitely take a look.

Answer (score 0):

You can select the class name and press **Ctrl + h** 'in Eclipse or STS' and copy the Fully qualified class name

You can use * at the end of the package name instead of the class name to select all classes in this package

**For Example:**
I have a class called **Home** in a package called **com.example.test** 
If I wanna to select only this class, the fully qualified class name will be **com.example.test.Home** 
If I have More than one class in this package and I wanna to select them all, the fully qualified classes name will be **com.example.test.***